# Exponential backoff for google-api-nodejs-client

Tags: google-api-nodejs-client

Does google-api-nodejs-client provide exponential backoff or does it handle the limit of API usage?

Answer (score 2):

It does provide a mechanism to retry requests with exponential backoff on specific status codes.
Support was added [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-googleapis-common/pull/104).